# Finding duplicate rows in two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I have database with two tables `Material` and `Mandatory`.

`Mandatory` table contains two columns `Class` and `Characteristic_Name`.

`Material` table contains four columns `Material_Name`, `Class`, `Characteristic_Name`, and `Characteristic_value`.

I want to show the `Material_Name` that has the same `Class`, `Characteristic_Name` and `Characteristic_value` where Class, Characteristic_Name are the same in the `Mandatory` table.

For example

`Material` table contain this data

```
Material_Name   Class   Characteristic_Name Characteristic_Value
-----------------------------------------------------------------
000000001       Class1  Model                       12
000000001       Class1  Size                         1
000000001       Class1  Type                        A
000000002       Class1  Model                       12
000000002       Class1  Size                         1
000000002       Class1  Type                        A
000000003       Class2  Type                        B
000000003       Class2  weight                      55
```

`Mandatory` table contains this data:

```
Class   Characteristic_Name
-------------------------------
Class1  Model
Class1  Size
Class1  Type
Class2  Type
Class2  weight
```

Material_Name 00000001 and 000000002 is the same because they have the same class, Characteristic_Name and  Characteristic_Value

What the query will show these results?

Comment: use groupby in your statement?

Comment: i don't know i'm try with some quires but doesn't arrive to the correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a complicated question.  If I understand correctly, you want pairs of materials where the mandatory fields match.  But, the mandatory fields vary by class, so the simply solution of pivoting the data does not work easily.

```
with m as (
      select m.*
      from (select m.*,
                   count(*) over (partition by m.material_name) as numMandatoryMatches,
                   numMandatory
            from material m join
                 (select ma.*, count(*) over (partition by ma.class) as numMandatory
                  from mandatory ma
                 ) ma
                 on m.class = ma.class and
                    m.Characteristic_Name = ma.Characteristic_Name
           ) m
      where numMandatoryMatches = numMandatory
    ) 
select m.material_name, m2.material_name
from m join
     m m2
     on m2.class = m.class and
        m2.Characteristic_Name = m.Characteristic_Name and
        m2.Characteristic_Value = m.Characteristic_Value
group by m.material_name, m2.material_name
having count(*) = max(m.nummandatoryMatches);
```

The CTE just gets materials that have all the mandatory fields.  The main `select` is just a cross join that checks that all the values match.

I should note that this assumes that characteristics are not repeated for a given field -- although it could be modified to handle that situation.

Comment: may be two or more

Comment: i try it but i want one answer no four answers and what if the result more than two???